# How to save ink strokes along with background in a GIF in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a canvas with a transparent background. Strokes are drawn over it. While saving using `SaveAsync` method of the `InkManager` class, it saves only the strokes not the transparent background. Is there any way by which I can save the background too ?

Else if there a way by which I can render the `InkManager` strokes on a `WritableBitmap` ?

This is how I am currently saving.

```
StorageFile Ink_File = await m_localfolder.CreateFileAsync(path, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

using (var stream = await Ink_File.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
    {
        uint x = await i.SaveAsync(outputStream);
        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

***The hard way:***

Well the way to do this in pure C# is to "load" the rendered **GIF** and the **background** you want to use as `WritableBitmap`s into memory.  After you have bitmap representations of both copy the pixel data from the background bitmap's `PixelBuffer` to a `byte[]`, you'll use that to composite the strokes on top of.  Now use the `PixelBuffer` of the **GIF** image to step through discarding all the pixels that are transparent combining any ones that aren't onto your `byte[]` that started off as the plain background image, be careful with dimensions here as you have to do a little math to figure out what `byte` corresponds to what color channel on what pixel. This is all very rigorous but not very difficult.

***The easy way:***

**Luckily for you, someone took the bother of wrapping all this kind of `byte[]` manipulating stuff up into a nice portable library that people seem to love, available here: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/**

Basically, that library will give you access to normal drawing and "bitblt-ing" (a.k.a. bit-block-transferring) functionality.  So now you should be able to "blt" the transparent image over the top of the opaque one to get your composite in just a few lines a code. No mess, no loops...  hope this helps -ck